# How activity instance creation is handled in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

My app has the following activities. A B C D. 
I launch app .. so going to A --> B (startActivity - Intent for B)
from B --> C (startActivity - Intent for C)
from C --> D (startActivity - Intent for D)

Here in D I have 2 buttons. one takes to B and another to C
If user clicks B button I do startActivity - Intent for B ======> Does this create a new instance of activity B or reuse the already existing instance of B? If it doesnt reuse is there a way we can have it reuse the existing activity instance.

Note: I don't need to worry about the state of instance as all fields are static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

associate the

`android:launchMode="singleTask"` with your activity tag activity B in your manifest file

for further reference you can refer to link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode